# Calculate profit and loss from income, expense, deposite and whithdraw tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I've been trying to find a solution for a sql query to show sum of Incomes, expenses, deposites,  withdraws of 
And group by Driver name.
The problem is that if some of the records are 
It doesn't show anything.
But if in case I have atleast one record in every table 
The records are some how are multiplied by number of rows of other tables. I could write the following query but it's not the best and perfect solution.

```
SELECT top 1  (SELECT Sum(CarIncome.income_amt)  FROM CarIncome )  AS [مجموع درآمد پیره های موتر ها],
 (SELECT Sum(DriverExpenses.driver_expense_amt) FROM DriverExpenses ) AS [مجموع مصارف درایور ها],
 (SELECT Sum(DriversDeposite.driver_deposite_amt) FROM DriversDeposite) AS [مجموع مبلغ حواله شده به درایور ها] ,
 (SELECT Sum(DriversWithdraw.driver_withdraw_amt) FROM DriversWithdraw ) AS [مجموع برداشت درایور ها],
 ((SELECT Sum(DriverExpenses.driver_expense_amt) FROM DriverExpenses ) +  (SELECT Sum(DriversDeposite.driver_deposite_amt) FROM DriversDeposite)) AS [مجموع مصارف و معاشات درایور ها],
 ((SELECT Sum(DriversDeposite.driver_deposite_amt) FROM DriversDeposite) - (SELECT Sum(DriversWithdraw.driver_withdraw_amt) FROM DriversWithdraw )) as [مجموع متباقی معاش قابل پرداخت درایور ها],
 ((SELECT Sum(CarIncome.income_amt)  FROM CarIncome ) -  ((SELECT Sum(DriverExpenses.driver_expense_amt) FROM DriverExpenses ) + (SELECT Sum(DriversDeposite.driver_deposite_amt) FROM DriversDeposite))) as [درآمد خالص موتر ها],
 (((SELECT Sum(DriversDeposite.driver_deposite_amt) FROM DriversDeposite) -(SELECT Sum(DriversWithdraw.driver_withdraw_amt) FROM DriversWithdraw )) + ((SELECT Sum(CarIncome.income_amt)  FROM CarIncome ) - ((SELECT Sum(DriverExpenses.driver_expense_amt) FROM DriverExpenses ) +  (SELECT Sum(DriversDeposite.driver_deposite_amt) FROM DriversDeposite)))) as [مجموع پول موجود در دست]
 FROM CarIncome, DriverExpenses, DriversDeposite, DriversWithdraw
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Wow. That is a lot of subqueries.

Comment: Thank u sir for editing the query

Comment: Yup lots of subqueries but that is the only solution I got which is not  perfect

Comment: "The records are some how are multiplied by number of rows of other tables."  -   They are somehow multiplied like this because your script is telling it to do so. You are doing a giant cross join in your from clause (you have no code to tell it how to join the 4 tables listed casuing 'some how multiplied' effect).  From your query, I would have to guess there is not one ID field and you are simply summing up the numbers getting sum(summed values from t1* num rows in table 2 * num rows in table 3 * num rows in table 4). Post you table design, there are far better ways of approaching this.

Comment: Tables structure are as following:

Comment: Table driver--------------driverID int  Pķ, Firstname varchar, lastname varchar

Comment: DriversDeposite------DepositeID int PK,  DriverID int FK, Date Date, Description varchar, amt int

Comment: DriverExpenses-----ExpenseID int PK, DriverID int FK, Date Date,  Description varchar, amt int

Comment: DriverWithdraw---withdrawID int PK, DriverID int FK, Date Date, Description varchar, amt int

Comment: The (SELECT TOP 1 ( subqueries ....)) solves the Cartesian problem sir, but still it's not perfect

Answer (score 0):

Your rows are getting multiplied because you're using a [Cartesian product](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_garmany_9_sql_cross_join.htm)

Your whole design doesn't make sense.
You basically have to entities, car and driver.
So you can do with two tables, tblCar and tblDriver.
You can use a column in tblDriver to capture the transaction type (expense, withdraw, deposit).

I suggest to invest some time in studying normalization and basic SQL and start from scratch.

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion Sir, The tables are normalized sir but I have problems in selecting the sum of the records from tables.

Comment: Your "driver" tables reflect **different types of** transactions. Bottom line, these are all transactions hence your tables are definitely not normalized.

Comment: Can you please write a query to solve the problem for now because I already have spended a month developing an Application based on these tables. I'll try improving my sql skills. And thank you dear.

Answer (score 0):

Since your SQL skills are limited, break down the problem into smaller problems. Start by creating saved queries for each sub-table, like this:

```
SELECT DriverID, SUM(amt) AS Deposite FROM DriversDeposite GROUP BY DriverID
```

Doing this will give you a query for each of your sub-tables with the sum of the amount per driver. Then all you have to do is create your final query that links (with OUTER JOINs not INNER ones) your drivers table with each of these queries.

You can do all this using the GUI, you don't need to write the SQL code yourself.

Comment: I created the subqueries as you said sir but I have no idea how to write the final query and link it to [ drivers table] .I need your help again sir

Comment: I could figure it out sir thank you very much, I couldn't do it with out your help